# Variable titles

Tags: views, 7

I am using views and I want to make the title be: Username's Wall. Depending whose profile it is viewing the title should be automatically changed. How can I do that? this is for drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the following, in the view title field:

> %user:name's Wall

Did you mean that you want to create a user profile page? Just use the [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module, activate the user profile template, and in the title pane write the following:

> %user:name's Wall

Comment: I just copied & paste that in title field in views and it just shows up as %user:name's Wall. It doesn't change to the username's name.

Comment: I don't think tokens are supported in views title field. You could override the template for the display, `global` the user object, and replace the `print $title`statement with `print $user->name . "'s Wall"`.